# Contact Form 7 validation is not working when submitting for the first time but it works fine when second time sumbit button is clicked

Tags: wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

Validation is not working in first click on submit button in contact form 7 form. On the first click it loads the page like https://example.com/#wpcf7-f783-o1 and when click second time on button in this page, the validation works. I am using "ReCaptcha v2 for Contact Form 7" plugin for captcha. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

first, recheck your validation and
check plugin is updated or not and check if any other plugin reflects or not.

Comment: I have checked that. My plugin is updated and I have checked that any other reflects or not...there is no issue in these.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).